# Parse/MongoDB using dates in ISO format as keys in dictionary

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, dictionary, parse-platform

I have a dictionary of timestamps where I want the `date in ISO Format` to be the `key` and a `string of what occured on the date` to be the `value`.

ex. `timestamps[date.toISOString()] = "SignedUp"`

The ISO String by default is `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.AZ`, so I'm getting this issue:

`[Error]: Nested keys should not contain the '$' or '.' characters`

Is there a way I can use the ISO Date String without getting this issue? Our backend stores dates using this format for everything so I'd prefer if it could stay that way. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB:

> Field names cannot contain dots (i.e. .) or null characters, and they must not start with a dollar sign (i.e. $)

[Source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names)

You can either replace the dot in your ISO8601 string with another accepted character (but you have to remember to convert it back again) or alternatively, use number of milliseconds since Unix epoch using the [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) function as your keys.

Comment: That's definitely an option, but I was hoping for something like in python where you can add `check_keys=False` and still use `$` and `.` keys